# How do I design a generic method with a new() constraint if it's only taking in non-concrete objects?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm having trouble designing this system that creates instances from a prototype object.  Here's what I have:

```
Dictionary<Type, IFoo> Prototypes;
object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    IFoo value;
    if (!Prototypes.TryGetValue(type, out value))
    {
        value = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IFoo;
        Prototypes.Add(type, value);
    }
    return Create(value as object);
}

T Create<T>(T instance) where T : new()
{
    return new T(); // this just returns a new blank object
}
```

I know that the problem is that I can't guarantee these objects to have a parameterless constructor.  But what can I do then?  There's no way to specify in IFoo to have a parameterless constructor, is there?  The only thing I can think of is to have a simple Create() function specified in IFoo, but I was hoping there'd be a solution that doesn't involve injecting a ton of new boilerplate code into my codebase.

And I can't call Activator.CreateInstance() every time, because of performance issues (I'll be running this function a lot).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Not related to the question, but your Create function will always create an `Object`, regardless of what type you pass in (and regardless of what `value` is). You can also change your `CreateInstance` signature to be templated, and add the where T : new() restriction

Comment: I think your problem is that c# has other features to address your design problem, as you haven't specified a use case I'm not actually sure how you want to use this but my instinct is that. as a starting point researching the factory and decorator design patterns in c# will point you in the right direction

Comment: @leemo: my use case is that I'm trying to write my own (de)serialization stuff.  I'm writing the objects' Type to the file, then reading the Type back, and now I'm trying to instantiate them somehow, without using too much reflection.  All the solutions I find use the built in serialization classes.  How do people do it normally?

Comment: Normally, people use the built-in serialization classes (or a library). You can't really do deserialization without reflection. Have you measured your code's speed and determined that it's too slow? Have you determined that the slow part is reflection?

Comment: What about specifying multiple constraints on the `CreateInstance` method? Like `IFoo CreateInstance<T>() where T :IFoo, new()` It doesn't force implementers into having a parameterless constructor, but does force them to have one if they use this creation pattern...

Comment: @Ron: All I have is the Type object, is there a way to use that to plug into that method?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I haven't tried the normal implementation yet, but I have a feeling it won't be sufficient.  It's a really performance critical application and I need to read/write huge files.  But you're right, I should definitely look into using it.

Comment: @terence You can verify the type has a parameterless constructor via reflection and throw an exception if it doesn't. You can also (through some pretty tough reflection) instantiate a generic method using a `Type`.

Comment: @terence definitely look into it. Unless there's some reason that your data can be processed particularly quickly (do you only have a few types that you could special-case?), a library that a lot of people put a lot of time into writing is likely to be faster than your implementation.

Comment: And reflection is not *that* slow, in any case. You should always test performance before you optimize. Otherwise, how do you know whether you're improving things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that generics are a compile-time feature. You are trying to create objects where the type is determined at run-time.

Therefore, you can't use generics to do this.

When you call `Create(value as object);`, the type parameter `T` is `object` (because it's inferred at compile-time from the compile-time type of the argument), so you get a `new object()` returned.

You could call `Create<Foo>` and get another `Foo` instance, but there's just no way to take `Type type` and call the appropriate `Create<Type>` without heavy use of reflection.

Comment: :( Is there a recommended alternative method for creating new objects dynamically?  For example, I could create a big static collection mapping Types to an instance, but that's difficult to maintain.

Comment: Honestly, creating new objects dynamically is a problem that reflection is designed to solve. You *could* look into using an object pool or something, but I highly recommend you write the "simple" solution first, then test its performance to see whether you need to make things more complex.

Comment: `+1` for simple solution first.  BTW, one solution I saw with NHibernate (Which is *highly* optimized for performance) is to generate IL code at runtime which creates the type, and stores a delegate for later use.  This is non-trivial.  Look into the [System.Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.